# Wrong executed SQL Statement error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

TL;DR: How do I make the table refresh with the new, updated columns?

Hi, I'm getting an `error` which states that I have invalid `column` names. The `column` names which are `invalid` have been deleted before hand and updated then.

When I `refresh` the table's data, the error is displayed again stating: `SELECT TOP [1000]`, `Error Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider` and the `invalid` `column` names.

The `error` is straight forward, but how do I manage to change the "default" `refresh` query of the `table`? I checked the `table` from `SQL Managment Studio` and `Visual Studio` and everything seems right... it's just that this query is not adapting to the `update` which I done to the table. This table had a `foreign key` with another `table` but I'm sure that I deleted any links with other `tables`.

Just in case this is the code of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Receipt] (
[receiptID]          INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[employeeUser]       NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[purchasedProductID] INT           NULL,
[productName]        NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[clientID]           INT           NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([receiptID] ASC)
```

);

Thanks alot and take care!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

Apparently the "Did you try turning it on/off" method work sometimes...

I restarted my visual studio project and worked.